# per unit method question

Tags: short-circuit

I just want to know why did he parallel the two apparent powers?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Paralleling" the two apparent powers seems to be a way of assuming that the PU impedance of the larger transformer is comparable to the PU impedance of the smaller one and accounting for that impedance (and any other other upstream impedance) in series with the smaller transformer. That may be a standard practice in power distribution system analysis. If you don't know the actual impedance of the larger upstream transformer, that would be a conservative assumption that you could make. If you have multiple-choice answers to choose from, you could probably safely choose using the assumption that the impedance upstream of the 1.5 MVA transformer is zero.